# Spring Web Service Request with empty URI and null Marshaller

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jdbc

I've generated domain classes from a WSDL using JABX and implemented the following client:

```
@Service
public class AccountEndpoint extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(AccountEndpoint.class));

    public AccountEndpoint() {
    }

    public GetAccountResponse getAccount(long accountAgency, long accountNumber) {
        GetAccountRequest request = new GetAccountRequest();
        request.setAccountAgency(accountAgency);
        request.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);

        GetAccountResponse response = (GetAccountResponse)
                getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I'm configuring it like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.myco.mypro.core"})
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() throws Exception {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("org.myco.mypro.webservices");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountEndpoint accountEndpoint(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        AccountEndpoint client = new AccountEndpoint();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:11000/ws");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

And testing:

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebServiceConfig.class)
public class AccountEndpointTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private AccountEndpoint accountEndpoint;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAccount() throws Exception {

        accountEndpoint.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:11000/ws");
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("org.myco.mypro.webservices");
        accountEndpoint.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        accountEndpoint.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

        GetAccountResponse response = accountEndpoint.getAccount(12, 16);

        assertNotNull(response);
    }
}
```

If I do not set the URI I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'uri' must not be empty`;

If I do not set the marshaller I get: `IllegalStateException: No marshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate.`

Its like the configuration in the WebServiceConfig isn't working, despite the bean autowired is not null.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: In case you're still monitoring StackOverflow - what was you ultimate solution?  Can you post?  thx

Answer (score 3):

You should take out the @Service annotation from AccountEndpoint. 
The bean is created in the configuration class.